# When you call remove(object o) on an arraylist, how does it compare objects?

Tags: java, arraylist, compare

When you call remove(object o) on an arraylist in java, how does it compare the objects to find the correct one to remove? does it use the pointer? or does it compare the objects using the interface Comparable?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`ArrayList` `remove()` relies on the objects implementation of the `Equal` method. If no implementation has been done then the object is removed by `Object`'s implementation of `Equals` which indeed is the pointer comparison.

From the documentation on `ArrayList` -

> More formally, removes the element with the lowest index i such that `(o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i)))` (if such an element exists)

Object `equal` method documentation -

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, this method returns true if and only if `x` and `y` refer to the same object (`x == y` has the value `true`).

Answer (score 11):

You should always consult the API for this kind of information.

> [`ArrayList.remove(Object o)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29): Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present. If the list does not contain the element, it is unchanged. More formally, removes the element with the lowest index `i` such that `(o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i)))`  (if such an element exists).

Perhaps you were confusing this with e.g. `TreeSet`:

> [`java.util.TreeSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html): Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be *consistent with equals* if it is to correctly implement the `Set` interface. (See Comparable  or Comparator for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so because the `Set` interface is defined in terms of the `equals` operation, but a `TreeSet` instance performs all element comparisons using its `compareTo` (or `compare`) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal.

(Unfortunately e.g. [`TreeSet.remove`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) method itself doesn't have any explicit reminder of the above caveat, but at least it's prominently placed at the top of the class documentation)

---

#### An illustrative example

The following snippet illustrates the difference in behaviors between collections that use `equals` (such as an `ArrayList`) and collections that use `compare/compareTo` (such as a `TreeSet`).

```
import java.util.*;

public class CollectionEqualsCompareTo {
    static void test(Collection<Object> col, Object o) {
        col.clear();
        col.add(o);
        System.out.printf("%b %b %b %b%n",
            col.contains(o),
            col.remove(o),
            col.contains(o),
            col.isEmpty()
        );
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object broken1 = new Comparable<Object>() {
            // Contract violations!!! Only used for illustration!
            @Override public boolean equals(Object o)    { return true; }
            @Override public int compareTo(Object other) { return -1;   }
        };
        Object broken2 = new Comparable<Object>() {
            // Contract violations!!! Only used for illustration!
            @Override public boolean equals(Object o)    { return false; }
            @Override public int compareTo(Object other) { return 0;     }
        };
        test(new ArrayList<Object>(), broken1); // true true false true
        test(new TreeSet<Object>(),   broken1); // false false false false
        test(new ArrayList<Object>(), broken2); // false false false false
        test(new TreeSet<Object>(),   broken2); // true true false true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) answer your question:

> Removes a single instance of the
>   specified element from this
>   collection, if it is present (optional
>   operation). More formally, removes an
>   element `e` such that `(o==null ? e==null
>   : o.equals(e))`, if the collection
>   contains one or more such elements.

Answer (score 1):

It uses `equals()`

from the [docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/):

> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present. If the list does not contain the element, it is unchanged. More formally, removes the element with the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i)))  (if such an element exists). Returns true if this list contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this list changed as a result of the call).