# How to remove particular bean object from ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I want to remove particular bean object from ArrayList.
I am using **remove** and **removeAll** method for delete the object element from ArrayList, but not remove element.

for example, assume below code,

```
ArrayList<SystemDetailData> systemDetails = new ArrayList<SystemDetailData>();
SystemDetailData data = new SystemDetailData();
data.setId("1");
data.setName("abc");
data.setHost("192.168.1.2");
systemDetails.add(data);

data = new SystemDetailData();
data.setId("2");
data.setName("asd");
data.setHost("192.168.1.45");
systemDetails.add(data);
System.out.println("Before remove : " + systemDetails);

ArrayList<SystemDetailData> systemDetail = new ArrayList<SystemDetailData>();
SystemDetailData data = new SystemDetailData();
data.setId("1");
data.setName("abc");
data.setHost("192.168.1.2");
systemDetail.add(data);
System.out.println("Old data :" + systemDetail);

//Remove object from arraylist - method1
systemDetails.removeAll(systemDetail);


//Remove object from arraylist - method2
systemDetails.removeAll(systemDetail.getId());
systemDetails.removeAll(systemDetail.getName());
systemDetails.removeAll(systemDetail.getHost());
System.out.println("After remove : "+systemDetails);
```

Bean Class :

```
public class SystemDetailData extends BusinessData {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final String DOMAIN_NAME = "domainName";
private static final String HOST_NAME = "hostName";
private static final String USER_NAME = "userName";
private static final String PASSWORD = "password";
private static final String INDEX = "index";

private BigInteger index;
private String domainName;
private String hostName;
private String userName;
private String password;


public BigInteger getIndex() {
    return (BigInteger) get (INDEX);
}

public void setIndex(BigInteger index) {
    set (INDEX, index);
    this.index = index;
}

public String getDomainName() {
    return (String) get(DOMAIN_NAME).toString();
}

public void setDomainName(String domainName) {
    set (DOMAIN_NAME, domainName);
    this.domainName = domainName;
}

public String getHostName() {
    return (String) get (HOST_NAME);
}

public void setHostName(String hostName) {
    set (HOST_NAME, hostName);
    this.hostName = hostName;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return (String) get (USER_NAME);
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    set (USER_NAME, userName);
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return (String) get (PASSWORD);
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    set (PASSWORD, password);
    this.password = password;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SystemDetailData [index=" + index + ", domainName="
            + domainName + ", hostName=" + hostName + ", userName="
            + userName + ", password=" + password + "]";
}

@Override
public String getKeyValue() {
    String value = "";
    if (index != null) {
        value = value + "INDEX =" + index + ";";
    }
    if (domainName != null) {
        value = value + "DOMAIN_NAME =" + domainName + ";";
    }
    if (userName != null) {
        value = value + "USER_NAME =" + userName + ";";
    }
    if (hostName != null) {
        value = value + "HOST_NAME =" + hostName + ";";
    }
    if (password != null) {
        value = value + "PASSWORD =" + password + ";";
    }
    return value;
}


}
```

I got below output :

```
Before remove : [SystemDetailData [index=1, Name=abc, host=192.168.1.2], SystemDetailData [index=2, Name=asd, host=192.168.1.45]]
Old data : [SystemDetailData [index=1, Name=abc, host=192.168.1.2]]

After remove : [SystemDetailData [index=1, Name=abc, host=192.168.1.2], SystemDetailData [index=2, Name=asd, host=192.168.1.45]]
```

I want below output :

```
After remove : [SystemDetailData [index=2, Name=asd, host=192.168.1.45]]
```

Comment: Can you explain why the current code doesn't do what you want?

Comment: i want remove the object from arraylist but not removed object for above scenario. please help me...

Comment: Can you post the code of SystemDetailData please?

Comment: The object in the `ArrayList` and the one you are supplying to the remove function are not equal, even though they have the same values. So the remove call is not finding a matching object to remove and therefore the container still has 2 elements. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894618/when-you-call-removeobject-o-on-an-arraylist-how-does-it-compare-objects

Answer (score 3):

If the SystemDetailData Class you have to implement hashcode and equals method. To expand my answer, In java when you want to delete an Object from a collection. Java check if the Object you want to delete is in this collection ( if Collection contains an Object which is equals to the one we want to delete). It uses the method equals. So we have to tell (explain) to Java what is for us the same Object: it can have the same name or the same id or another property ( attribute ). This is a reason why we have to implements equals (and hashcode)

Comment: It would really help other people reading this answer to explain why this is required.

Comment: The posted bean class is not point the above scenario. just assume the above scenario to implement my requirement. is it possible or not? post small example... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your SystemDetailData class needs to implement an equals method. When you call remove on the ArrayList, the code is doing something like:

```
ArrayList<SystemDetailData> items;
void remove(SystemDetailData itemToRemove) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < items.size() ++i ) {
        if ( items.get(i).equals(itemToRemove) ) {
            items.remove(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

he 
So unless the equals method returns true for the item you are passing into the remove method and an item in your collection, nothing wil be removed.

You need to decide exactly what the equals method should look like but if, for example, two items are the same if the ids are the same then you could just add a method to SystemDetailData like:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    SystemDetailData otherData = (SystemDetailData)other;
    return otherData.getId() == this.getId();
}
```

Obviously you'll need to add checks for null, the type of other etc. but that should give you an idea of what the method needs to look like.