# DataTable always removing the first line

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Good Guys,
I have this Web app, after implementing the DataTable from PrimeFaces Showcase, I realized that by clicking on remove a line it always removes the first line in the DataTable, a little help would be welcome.

My DataTable Code:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{facturaBean.consultasTemp}" paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{consulta.ordem}"  rows="5" paginator="true" widgetVar="tblConsultas" var="consulta">
                        <p:column style="text-align: center" headerText="Operação" width="100">
                            <p:commandButton style="font-size: 17px" icon="fa fa-trash-o" action="#{facturaBean.removerConsulta(consulta)}" update="@form"/>
                            
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Consulta/Procedimento">
                            <h:outputText value="#{consulta.consulta}"></h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Data/Hora">
                            <h:outputText value="#{consulta.consultaData}"></h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Médico">
                            <h:outputText value="#{consulta.consultaMedico}"></h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Valor (MT)">
                            <h:outputText value="#{consulta.consultaValor}"></h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Quantidade">
                            <h:outputText value="#{consulta.consultaQuantidade}"></h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Valor Total (MT)">
                            <h:outputText value="#{consulta.consultaValorTotal}"></h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
```

Removing Line Method:

private ArrayList consultasTemp = new ArrayList();

```
public String removerConsulta(ConsultaTemp consulta) {
    consultasTemp.remove(consulta);
    return null;
}
```

Video for details:
[enter link description here](https://youtu.be/NEx0SYHEHt0)

Comment: Did you implement an `equals` method in `ConsultaTemp`?

Comment: I'd try to not pass an entire `ConsultaTemp` instance to the method but the key onl (I assume this would be named `ordem`).

Comment: @Thomas even in the pass the key (order) in ConsultaTemp he continues to remove the first row.

Comment: @JasperdeVries no.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894618/when-you-call-removeobject-o-on-an-arraylist-how-does-it-compare-objects

Comment: When passing the key instead of the item, how did you adjust your `removerConsulta()` method? Did you check the correct key is being passed and did you only remove the item that has that key?

Comment: I'v also not been using JavaEL in years but if `#{facturaBean.removerConsulta(consulta)}` doesn't execute right away (which actually might be the case so please check) then passing an entire `consulta` instance from the client to the backend should result in a new instance being passed to to `removerConsulta()`. If that is the case then not overriding `Object.equals()` should result in nothing being removed at all. So you might want to step through your code with a debugger and check when that method gets called and what got passed (specifically check the instance id).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all very much for your help and knowledge, but I was unable to remove rows using the **rowKey="#{consulta.ordem}"** attribute of the DataTable, instead of this I created the following class:

```
public String removerConsulta(ConsultaTemp consulta) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < consultasTemp.size(); i++) {
        if (consultasTemp.get(i).getConsulta().equals(consulta.getConsulta())) {
            consultasTemp.remove(i);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```